# Already have htaccess but permalink settings not working. Getting 404

Tags: permalinks, mod-rewrite

I have a .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

the config for the vhost looks like

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName elements
    DocumentRoot /works/web/elements
    <Directory /works/web/elements>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from 127.0.0.1
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

But I am still getting 404 when I view pages, why is that?

Comment: Is mod_rewrite enabled? What errors are you seeing in your logs?

Comment: Are you getting a 404 through WordPress, or one generated by Apache?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, Apache

Comment: @anu, ah ... I was thinking `AllowOverride All` enabled mod_rewrite, but I was wrong... I needed to enable mod_rewrite ... I used  `a2enmod rewrite`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was not having mod_rewrite enabled ...

Resolved it through

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```